# Outlook 2013 : Add custom button to outlook mail inbox window

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2013

In the outlook 2013, in the Inbox folder, we have list of emails.

When selecting a email, it previews it in the Right side panel with button of Reply,Reply All and forward on the header of that panel.

I want to add the custom button in header.

Please see red color highlighted box, where exactly I want to add custom button.

[image]

I have tries below code, but it will add button to context menu.

http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/building-outlook-2010-add-using-cnet-visual-studio-2010

Also, I have checked below link to add custom button on different places in Outlook. But I could not find anything to add button on the Right side preview panel.

[Add custom button in Outlook](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm)

Please suggest.

Thank you,
Mittal.

Answer (score 0):

That area in Outlook is not customizable.